# SwiftUI Using @StateObject and @EnvironmentObject at the same time

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am studying swiftUI!

I'm worried that viewModel initialization is being called twice.

It is an mvvm pattern, and the view is divided for readability.

Am I misunderstanding my configuration?

HomeView.swift

```swift
struct HomeView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject private var coordinator: Coordinator
    @StateObject var homeViewModel = HomeViewModel()
    
    init() {
        print("HomeView init!")
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HomeButtons()
            
            TodaysCommit()

            CharacterView()

            CharacterInfo()
        }
        .environmentObject(homeViewModel)
        .onReceive(homeViewModel.$outputEvent) { event in
            if let event = event {
                receiveViewModelEvent(event)
            }
        }
    }
 
}
```

```swift
struct HomeButtons: View {
    @State private var showParticipating = false
    @State private var showingSheet = false
    @EnvironmentObject private var homeViewModel: HomeViewModel

    
    var body: some View {
        
        HStack {
            Button {
                homeViewModel.requestUserInfo()
            } label: {
                Image("refresh")
            }
            
            Spacer()
            Button {
                showParticipating.toggle()
            } label: {
                Image("collection")
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showParticipating) {
            CollectionListView()
        }
        .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 30, bottom: 0, trailing: 30))
    }
    
    init() {
        UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        navigationBarHidden(false)
    }
}
```

Log
HomeView init!

HomeViewModel init !

HomeViewModel init !

Any feedback or problems would be of great help!

have a good day :)

Comment: plausible but it depends on whatever is above HomeView. Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

It would be hard for me to comment on your app without seeing the other code, but I can give you some advice on using environmentObject.

If you decide to use .enviromentobject, the best way to use it is in yourAppNameApp.swift file. For example:

```
@main
struct yourAppNameApp: App {
    @StateObject var homeViewModel = HomeViewModel()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(homeViewModel)
        }
    }
}
```

This way, as you already know, you can access the viewmodel only from the view you need.

```
@EnvironmentObject private var homeViewModel: HomeViewModel
```